# When I press one of the items in the scroll-down button, it is not updated but when I randomly press on the screen, it is updated

Tags: flutter

When I press one of the items in the scroll-down button, it is not updated but when I randomly press on the screen, it is updated.

```
DropdownButton(
                  value: _selectedDifficulty,
                  items: Difficulty.values
                      .map((difficulty) => DropdownMenuItem(
                          value: difficulty,
                          child: Text(
                            difficulty.name,
                          )))
                      .toList(),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    if (value == null) {
                      return;
                    }
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedDifficulty = value;
                      
                    });
                  }),
```